# Are there flags for g++ that will make these errors easier to read?

Tags: c++, g++, vtable

I came across these C++ link errors. Maybe not specifically for *why* these happened, but I'd like know whether there are some `g++` flags that may make these error messages more readable, e.g., it doesn't really make sense for these symbols: `_ZN9`, `_ZTI12`, `+0x10`, etc.

```
g++ -o src/test.o -c -std=c++11 -Iinclude src/test.cpp
g++ -o observer5 src/test.o
src/test.o: In function `CObserver::CObserver()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN9CObserverC2Ev[_ZN9CObserverC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for CObserver'
src/test.o:(.rodata._ZTI12CDisplayHeat[_ZTI12CDisplayHeat]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for CObserver'
src/test.o:(.rodata._ZTI15CDisplayForcast[_ZTI15CDisplayForcast]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for CObserver'
src/test.o:(.rodata._ZTI13CDisplayStats[_ZTI13CDisplayStats]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for CObserver'
src/test.o:(.rodata._ZTI15CDisplayCurrent[_ZTI15CDisplayCurrent]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for CObserver'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I'm not sure which flags you can set here, but this looks like the error you'd get if you had an unimplemented virtual function in the class `CObserver`.

Comment: yeah thanks. Is it possible to make more sense of the error message, for example, is that `+0xf` really some offset to the source file where the error happened?

Comment: How familiar are you with vtables?

Comment: I'm not that familiar. My understanding is that a base class object has a vtable to determine exactly what virtual function to be ran at run time.

Comment: The error messages are happening at link time and not at compile time. The link just have access to machine language data (and not to the source code), so I think it can't show more friendly messages (but I'm not sure).

Comment: @Gomiero - yes you are right, these are link errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "vtable" is short for "virtual function table." When the compiler generates code for classes that have virtual functions, it assembles a table containing a bunch of pointers to the member functions of each polymorphic class. This table is then used to implement dynamic dispatch extremely efficiently.

The error you're getting here is a linker error indicating that your code compiled correctly (good!) but that the linker couldn't find the compiled code for the implementation of one or more member functions in a class with a vtable. Since it couldn't find those implementations, it couldn't generate the necessary vtables, so the linker reports that it can't turn the assembly into machine code. The information you're getting about offsets pertains to the generated assembly code, not your source file.

To fix this error, look over the referenced classes (here, `CObserver`) and check that, for each member function, you either

1. defined it somewhere (and correctly compiled the file containing the implementation), or
2. **marked it pure virtual** (so there's no missing vtable entry).

As for how to make these easier to read - I'm not sure. However, I've seen this error enough times that I can immediately tell what the problem is when I see it. I think with practice you'll get into the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one might say these are technically linker errors, but I've seen errors similar to this when I forget to define an interface class function as pure virtual.

For example

```
class IObserver
{
   virtual void DisplayHeat();
};
```

Instead of

```
class IObserver
{
   virtual void DisplayHeat() = 0;
};
```

And then later I inherit from it

```
class CObserver : public IObserver
{
....
};
```

Can you post snippets of your code perhaps?

Comment: My bad, looks like you're just asking why the errors are they way they are.

Comment: No, that's good. My Q is about how to make the error messages more clear. But your answer is also good to me.